# Node - extract only the message from callback error

Tags: node.js

Newbie to node. Just curious to know if node already has a way to just extract the error message   from an error object.

```
conn.query(sql, params, function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
...
}
```

in case of error , error message, the entire sql statement error is returned along with sql code . I would like to check the error and then return back an appropriate message based on the type of sql error like duplicate entry / length exceeds etc.

Is there a way just to extract the message alone from the callback error?

error message extraction

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to get the message object for this:

```
callback(err.message)
```

More information can be found here: [Errors | Node.js v19.7.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errormessage):

> ##### `error.message`
>
> The `error.message` property is the string description of the error as set by calling `new Error(message)`. The `message` passed to the constructor will also appear in the first line of the stack trace of the `Error`, however changing this property after the `Error` object is created *may not* change the first line of the stack trace (for example, when `error.stack` is read before this property is changed).

```js
const err = new Error('The message');
console.error(err.message);
// Prints: The message
```

Comment: thank you Praveen... The error message itself contains all the sql queries and many other info along with the descripton.. Not sure if there is a way to just have the description alone without the queries information?